# How to put breakpoint in every function of .cpp file?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, macros, envdte

Is there a macro that does it? Which DTE objects to use?

Comment: The strongest argument i've seen today to stop developing under windows and use linux with tools like gdb that will let you breakpoint on a file.

Answer (score 18):

(This is not quite what you're asking for, but almost:)

You can put a breakpoint on **every member function of a class** in Visual Studio by bringing up the *New Breakpoint* dialog and entering:

```
CMyClass::*
```

See [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick implementation of 1800 INFORMATION's idea:

```
Sub TemporaryMacro()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfDocument()
    Dim returnValue As vsIncrementalSearchResult
    While True
        DTE.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Object.ActivePane.IncrementalSearch.StartForward()
        returnValue = DTE.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Object.ActivePane.IncrementalSearch.AppendCharAndSearch(AscW("{"))
        DTE.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Object.ActivePane.IncrementalSearch.Exit()
        If Not (returnValue = vsIncrementalSearchResult.vsIncrementalSearchResultFound) Then
            Return
        End If
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint")
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GotoBrace")
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.CharRight()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but can't accept, because it doesn't work with namespaces.

Comment: If you're having troubles with namespaces, just comment out the first line that goes to the start of the document.  You'll need to manually place the cursor at the beginning of the block you want toggled, but it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what DTE functions to use, but you could very simply record a macro that could pretty much do it:

1. Go to the top of the file
2. ctrl - shift - R (start recording)
3. ctrl - I (incremental search)
4. { (search for the first { character).
5. F9 (set breakpoint)
6. ctrl - ] (go to matching } character)
7. ctrl - shift - R (stop recording)

Now just run this over and over (ctrl - shift P repeatedly) until you reach the end of the file.

If you have namespaces, then change 4. to:

4. ( (search for "(" at the start of the function definition)
5. esc (stop incremental search)
6. ctrl - I (incremental search again)
7. { (start of function body)

This kind of thing can be infinitely modified to suit your codebase

Comment: I have anonymous namespaces, will it work? (Don't have VS at the moment to check)

Comment: Actually (ignore my previous comment) it would obviously skip over the code inside the namespace. Try the change I edited in

Comment: Can't get this to work in VS 2010 -- incremental search is disabled while recording a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Like Constantin's method... This seems like windbg territory.

Since you have the cpp, (even if you didn't you could script something to get by), it should be no problem to use [logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266308.aspx) part of the debugging tools for windows... it's a very handy tool, shame so few people use it.

logger debug's C/COM/C++ easily, with rich symbolic info, hooks/profiling/flexible instrumentation;

[*One way to activate Logger is to start CDB or WinDbg and attach to a user-mode target application as usual. Then, use the !logexts.logi or !logexts.loge extension command.
This will insert code at the current breakpoint that will jump off to a routine that loads and initializes Logexts.dll in the target application process. This is referred to as "injecting Logger into the target application."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266315.aspx)

Comment: I've been wanting to learn more about this, I'm having a problem during loading and I want to see context this supposed duplication is occurring for some google protobuf exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how something similar could be achieved in WinDbg:

```
bm mymodule!CSpam::*
```

This puts breakpoint in every method of class (or namespace) `CSpam` in module `mymodule`.

I'm still looking for anything close to this functionality in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a macro, but I tested it only with c#.

```
Sub BreakAtEveryFunction()
For Each project In DTE.Solution.Projects
    SetBreakpointOnEveryFunction(project)
Next project
End Sub


Sub SetBreakpointOnEveryFunction(ByVal project As Project)
Dim cm = project.CodeModel

' Look for all the namespaces and classes in the 
' project.
Dim list As List(Of CodeFunction)
list = New List(Of CodeFunction)
Dim ce As CodeElement
For Each ce In cm.CodeElements
    If (TypeOf ce Is CodeNamespace) Or (TypeOf ce Is CodeClass) Then
        ' Determine whether that namespace or class 
        ' contains other classes.
        GetClass(ce, list)
    End If
Next

For Each cf As CodeFunction In list

    DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(cf.FullName)
Next

End Sub

Sub GetClass(ByVal ct As CodeElement, ByRef list As List(Of CodeFunction))

' Determine whether there are nested namespaces or classes that 
' might contain other classes.
Dim aspace As CodeNamespace
Dim ce As CodeElement
Dim cn As CodeNamespace
Dim cc As CodeClass
Dim elements As CodeElements
If (TypeOf ct Is CodeNamespace) Then
    cn = CType(ct, CodeNamespace)
    elements = cn.Members
Else
    cc = CType(ct, CodeClass)
    elements = cc.Members
End If
Try
    For Each ce In elements
        If (TypeOf ce Is CodeNamespace) Or (TypeOf ce Is CodeClass) Then
            GetClass(ce, list)
        End If
        If (TypeOf ce Is CodeFunction) Then
            list.Add(ce)
        End If
    Next
Catch
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, although normally i don't put C# code in .cpp files. I wonder if it also works for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it (I warn you it is hacky):

```
EnvDTE.TextSelection textSelection = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte.ActiveWindow.Selection;
// I'm sure there's a better way to get the line count than this...
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(dte.ActiveDocument.FullName).Length;
var methods = new List<CodeElement>();
var oldLine = textSelection.AnchorPoint.Line;
var oldLineOffset = textSelection.AnchorPoint.LineCharOffset;
EnvDTE.CodeElement codeElement = null;
for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    try
    {
        textSelection.MoveToLineAndOffset(i, 1);
        // I'm sure there's a better way to get a code element by point than this...
        codeElement =  textSelection.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction];
        if (codeElement != null)
        {
            if (!methods.Contains(codeElement))
            {
                methods.Add(codeElement);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Add error handling here.");
    }
}

// Restore cursor position
textSelection.MoveToLineAndOffset(oldLine, oldLineOffset);

// This could be in the for-loop above, but it's here instead just for
// clarity of the two separate jobs; find all methods, then add the
// breakpoints
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    dte.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(
        Line: method.StartPoint.Line,
        File: dte.ActiveDocument.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the top of the file:

```
#define WANT_BREAK_IN_EVERY_FUNCTION

#ifdef WANT_BREAK_IN_EVERY_FUNCTION
#define DEBUG_BREAK DebugBreak();
#else
#define DEBUG_BREAK 
#endif
```

then insert DEBUG_BREAK in the beginning of every function, like this:

```
void function1()
{
    DEBUG_BREAK
    // the rest of the function
}

void function2()
{
    DEBUG_BREAK
    // the rest of the function
}
```

When you no longer want the debug breaks, comment the line

```
// #define WANT_BREAK_IN_EVERY_FUNCTION
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: I'd like an unintrusive automated solution. I could just as well press F9 in each function.