# how to set break point on all function start in c++ file using visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have more than 100 files as source. Each of these files are atleast 1000 lines. In order to debug the **sequence of calls**, I want to put a break point on all the functions for all the files. There are plenty of COM Pointers in all the files.

1. Is it even possible with VS 2008 to set multiple break points?
2. I know this is a crazy idea, any optimization suggestion?

Comment: I was frustrated when I couldn't (figure out how to) do this with OllyDbg. Every debugger should have a "breakpoint range" feature IMO.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could try using code coverage or profiling tools instead.  If you set them up right, and execute your code in the right way, they can store data about individual call paths through the code.

Comment: hm, maybe you could write a VS macro that sets the breakpoints for you.

Comment: It isn't available.  The biggest issue with it is that it would take rather a long time before the program starts running.  Setting a breakpoint is an expensive operation.  Debugging is a divide-and-conquer kind of operation.  You would very quickly tire out from the gazillion pointless breaks if you break on all functions.  It just isn't practical, thus not available.

Comment: @Hans he did say "on all the functions for all the files", not "on every function call". Now _that_ would be a mess.

Comment: @celavek more like sequence diagram. awx nice suggestion, let me try that

Comment: There are times when I would also like a feature like this (maybe scoped to a particular file or set of files).  I don't much care what the performance would be - as long as it would be faster and more reliable than me doing it myself.  Computers are pretty good at that kind of busy work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put breakpoint in every function of .cpp file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160030/how-to-put-breakpoint-in-every-function-of-cpp-file)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a custom prologue to add a machine debug break to every function in the compilation unit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xy06s51(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but have you tried using the debug features "Step Into (F11)", "Step Over (F10)", and "Step Out (Shift+F11)"? That would effectively do the same thing I would imagine since you want to stop at each function call anyway.